# Что значит @ в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что значит `@` в Python? И почему его ставят перед кодом?

Вот в качестве примера код из модуля для написания бота в телеграм:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")
```

Этот код позволяет реагировать боту на `/start` и `/help`, но что такое `@`?

Comment: [Декоратор](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)

Comment: Почему бы, черт возьми, не почитать документацию?

Comment: Конкретно здесь это декоратор, как Вам уже сказали. Но ещё `@` может быть оператором перемножения матриц.

Comment: https://m.habr.com/ru/post/141411/ целая статья на хабре посвящённая этой теме

Answer (score 0):

Это называется "[декоратор](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)". Вкратце: это функция, которая выполняется каждый раз когда вызывается та, которая задекорирована.